# Isn't the phrase "minutes show" grammatically weird at the end of this text?

Tags: vocabulary, headlinese, learning

The headline:

"Fed officials anticipate 'significant' interest rate hikes until inflation eases, minutes show"

from [this source](https://www.foxbusiness.com/economy/fed-officials-anticipate-significant-interest-rate-hikes-inflation-eases-minutes-show).

Although I understood what was the link of "minutes show" to the text, in the beginning of it. I thought it was a very weak connection. I wonder if someone could be capable of understand it without the context, even native English speakers.

My question is if the: the "minutes show" phrase really make any sense? I'm afraid I misunderstood the correlation to the text.

Comment: Print media conventionally add the source of a news item to the end of the sentence or headline. The aim is to hit the reader's eye with the news rather than its source. This is pretty much universal practice.

Comment: It's not any stranger than *"I am going to the store," John said.*

Comment: @stangdon, or maybe "John is going to the store, he said". :)

Comment: @lynera!  The word "Minutes" means the "minutes of the meeting", that is to say, the official notes taken (written in a book, typed) which record what was said and done in the meeting.

Answer (score 18):

It is odd, but it is "headlinese".

Compare with

> My husband is an idiot, wife says.

For impact and style, the content of the quote is put first. The attribution is put in a bit at the end.  However, this is headlinese.  People don't talk like this.

By the way, in case it's not obvious, "minutes" are the detailed notes of the meeting, nothing to do with time.

Comment: For headlinese I would drop the "my" before "husband." But +1 anyway for that perfect example.

Comment: OP is asking the meaning of "minutes", it seems

Answer (score 5):

Journalists don't want to be accused of "editorialising", that is, injecting their own opinions into their reports. Therefore they try as much as possible to explicitly attribute things to the people or bodies that have written or said them.

In this case it is the meeting minutes (presumably of the federal body responsible for setting interest rates) that show they are predicting there will be significant rises.

Comment: OP is asking the meaning of "minutes", it seems